# mapping sub field issue

Tags: c#, automapper

I have problem when mapping my entities to my models.

entity class 1

```
enter public partial class Contact 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

class 2

```
public partial class City 
{
    public City()
    {
        Contact = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }
    public int ID  { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
}
```

The model for my contact is

```
 public class ContactViewModel 
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public KeyValueGeneric<int?, string> City = new KeyValueGeneric<int?, string>();
    }
```

I'm trying to map it like this:

```
        CreateMap<ContactViewModel, Contact>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CityId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.City.Id));


        CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.City.Id, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.CityId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.City.Value, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.City.Name));
```

but I'm getting:

> must resolve to top-level member and not any child object message

I'm gonna appreciate any help

Comment: Where is ContactType property defined on your entity / model? And why do separate CreateMap for same entity / model with reversal?

Comment: sorry itsnto that problem i removed those properties fromthe models to reduce the unecesary code 
he issue is with  the City Ketvaluegeneric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume it is because you are mapping to child properties:

```
dest.City.Id
```

Why not create a corresponding model for City (e.g. CityViewModel) and map to it directly?

```
CreateMap<City, CityViewModel>();


CreateMap<Contact, ContactViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.City, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.City));
```

If you do want to map to child properties, you may need to use ForPath() instead of ForMember(). E.g:

```
.ForPath(dest => dest.City.Id, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.CityId))
```

Comment: .ForPath(dest => dest.City.Id, input => input.MapFrom(src => src.CityId)) worked just fine !!